# antialiasing iPhone OpenGLES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, antialiasing

I need in antialiasing in iPhone 3G (OpenGL ES1.1), NOT iPhone 3Gs with OpenGL ES.2.0.
I've draw 3d model and have next: pixels on the edges of the model look like teeth.

I've try set any filters for texture, but this filters making ONLY texture INSIDE look better.

How can i make good antialising ?
May be i should use any smooth for drawing triangles ? If yes, then how it possible in OpenGL ES1.1 ?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render into a larger FBO and then use that as a texture on a square.

Have a look at [this](http://iphone-3d-programming.labs.oreilly.com/ch06.html#ch06_id36002707) article for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link!
And i'll try "render into a larger FBO".

Comment: I've posted a new answer: the concept is the same but there is an easier way to do it in newer versions of iOS.

Answer (score 8):

**As of iOS 4.0, full-screen anti-aliasing is directly supported via an Apple extension to OpenGL.** The basic concept is similar to epatel's suggestion: render the scene onto a larger framebuffer, then copy that down to a screen-sized framebuffer, then copy that buffer to the screen. The difference is, instead of creating a texture and rendering it onto a quad, the copy/sample operation is performed by a single function call (specifically, `glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE()`).

For details on how to set up the buffers and modify your drawing code, you can read [a tutorial on the Gando Games blog](http://www.gandogames.com/2010/07/tutorial-using-anti-aliasing-msaa-in-the-iphone/) which is written for OpenGL ES 1.1; there is also [a note on Apple's Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/45850) explaining the same thing.

Thanks to Bersaelor for [pointing this out in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813035/opengl-es-iphone-drawing-anti-aliased-lines/3806022#3806022).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS and EGL_SAMPLES parameters to [eglChooseConfig()](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/eglChooseConfig.xml), as well as [glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glEnable.xml).

EDIT: Hrm, [apparently](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8129808) you're out of luck, at least as far as standardized approaches go.  As mentioned in that thread you can render to a large off-screen texture and scale to a smaller on-screen quad or jitter the view matrix several times.

Comment: Thanks, but openGL on the iPhone has no support eglChooseConfig().
Or am I mistaken?
But when i set GL_LINE_SMOOTH and use glDrawArrays with GL_LINE_STRIP i have SUPER antialiased line.
But when i set GL_TRIANGLES then this effects is disappear.

Comment: Looks like you're right.  Odd.  Anyway, found a thread with some alternative approaches and edited the answer.

Comment: genpfault,

may be. i've googled more sites and feeling that there is only one way - try to use this http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=548956 or similar.

Answer (score 2):

We found another way to achieve this. If you edit your textures and add for example a 2 pixel frame of transparent pixels, the colored pixels in the texture are blended with the transparent pixels when necessary giving a basic anti-aliasing effect. You can read the full article here in [our blog](https://agileroute.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-emulate-anti-aliasing-in-opengl-es-1-1/).

The advantage of this approach is that you are not rendering a bigger image, or copying a buffer, or even worse, making a texture from a buffer, so there is no impact in performance.

Comment: This link to [our blog](http://agileroute.com/blog/how-to-emulate-anti-aliasing-in-opengl-es-1-1) is broken