# open GL ES basis applications

Tags: iphone

How can I draw an Ellipse using openGL ES

Answer (score 1):

There are many good tutorials that help you to learn Open GL ES. These tutorials particularly give examples to draw Ellipse, Circle, Square etc..

Some are here,

1. [OpenGL ES for iPhone  tutorial - By Simon Maurice](http://iphone-development-source-codes.blogspot.com/2012/01/opengl-es-tutorial-of-simon-maurice-for.html)
2. [Open GL 2.0 for iPhone tutorial - by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial)
3. [Resources for iPhone OpenGL ES  - Beginners / Intermediate](http://iphone-development-source-codes.blogspot.com/2012/02/resources-for-learning-iphone-opengl-es.html)

Best Wishes

Answer (score 0):

Draw a bunch of line segments around the circumference.

Also note that your system may not support anti-aliased lines (the iPhone doesn't). There's a nice article on drawing antialiased lines [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1669-how-to-render-anti-aliased-lines-with-textures-in-ios-4/). You can do something similar to draw the line segments (though you don't need the end-caps, so it's a bit simpler).

Another solution to anti-aliasing that requires more polygons is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813035/opengl-es-iphone-drawing-anti-aliased-lines).