# opengl-es 2D plotting library

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es, embedded

I’m looking for a small C/C++, opengles based plotting library. I’d like to represent multiple curves with different colors and some basic string displaying.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) library. It is free (GPL and LGPL for core) but not so small (large set of graphics types).

Comment: Hi,Than you for the answer. I forgt to say that i'm using some elgacy operating system where only Opengles 1.x is available. So integrating MathGL will be heavy in my case. I need to draw something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813035/opengl-es-iphone-drawing-anti-aliased-lines line rendering will be enough for me. The only need is X/Y axis and to be able to draw different lines using different colors. I'm not an opengles expert so any piece of code could be helfull. Thanks

Comment: Hi, MathGL use lines,triangles and quadrangles for primitives (so it should be OK even for v.1.*). Another question: may be you should prepare bitmap in memory first and display it later (instead of using OpenGL). In this case you will not need OpenGL at all.