# Rotated images having jagged borders even after adding transparent border

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, image-rotation

In my app I need to rotate images.I rotated the images but they have jagged borders.I googled and found that adding transparent border solves the problem, but the borders are still jagged.

My code is

```
-(void)CreateRotatedImage:(UIImage *)image Number:(int)Number    
            {    
                UIImage *ImageBackground=[UIImage imageNamed:@"white-highlight.png"];

CGSize ImageBackgroundSize = CGSizeMake(60, 50);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(ImageBackgroundSize);
CGRect ImageBackgroundRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ImageBackgroundSize.width, ImageBackgroundSize.height);
[ImageBackground drawInRect:ImageBackgroundRect];
ImageBackground = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



CGSize ImageSize = CGSizeMake(50, 40);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(ImageSize);
CGRect ImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ImageSize.width, ImageSize.height);
[image drawInRect:ImageRect];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();





UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(60,50));
[ImageBackground drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(5,5)];
// MyscrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



UIImage *pin=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(60,50));
[newImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
[pin drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(newImage.size.height/2,0)];
// MyscrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *IntermediateImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



CGRect imageRrect = CGRectMake(0, 0, IntermediateImage.size.width, IntermediateImage.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imageRrect.size ); 
[IntermediateImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(2,2,IntermediateImage.size.width-2,IntermediateImage.size.height-2)];    
   UIImage *i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



CGSize iSize = CGSizeMake(110, 70);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(iSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
 CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(5));
[i drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
UIImage *RotatedImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

//RotatedImage=[RotatedImage resizedImage:iSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];  


}
```

Comment: you have to use antialiased lines for borders
solution lies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813035/opengl-es-iphone-drawing-anti-aliased-lines/3806022#3806022