# Best Practice for Rounded Rectangles in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, rounded-corners, nine-patch

Using OpenGL ES, there seem to be two viable options for rounded rectangles:

1. Manually draw the shape using trig. (This is what I'm currently doing.)
2. Use a a texture or group of textures that scale appropriately, such as [9-Slice Scaling](http://www.centigrade.de/en/blog/article/modern-user-interface-design-tools-part-2-graphical-approach-of-gui-design-tools/)

The problem with the first option is that antialiasing does not come for free, and if you are aiming for compatibility with a wide array of devices, one can't count on OpenGL antialiasing hints to actually work on the hardware.  So you're left with choppy-looking rounded rectangles, especially for small ones, and the performance overhead of making another vertex array draw call.  I would like to switch away from this

The second option (9-Slice or 9-Patch) seems to be the go-to method for UI rounded rect elements, but there is surprisingly little information out there about implementing 9-patching in OpenGL ES.

What I would like is: an efficient strategy for rendering antialiased rounded rectangles in OpenGL ES with adjustable border widths, border colors and fill colors.  Any suggestions?

Comment: For the first option you can make antialiasing work by adding a thin border along the mesh. The vertices on the outside of the mesh have an alpha of 0 and the vertices inside an alpha of 1. If you modulate the color of your rounded rect by the alpha varying you'll get AA.

Comment: Any code samples or resources for how to use this method for arbitrary curved lines?

Comment: Check the answers in the 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560575/draw-a-rounded-rectangle-using-a-single-gldrawelement-triangle-strip-call-i/19782207#19782207

Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is essentially a technique called *Edge Anti-Aliasing*.

It is described very well in this answer: [OpenGL ES iPhone - drawing anti aliased lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813035/opengl-es-iphone-drawing-anti-aliased-lines)

Just apply the transparent vertexes at outmost borderline of your rectangle.